# Error on MySQl trigger and is there any way of better writing?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

Hello I get the following error when I use the trigger below:

```
inser into shift
-> values<15,3, '08:00:00','14:00:00'>;

ERROR 1048 <23000>: Column 'CashierCode' can not be null
```

Why is that? Also, is there any better writing of the following?

```
DELIMITER @
create trigger shist_start
before insert on shift
for each row
begin
if(new.CashierCode not in(
select w.EmployeeCode from WorksOn as w
join shop as s on w.ShopCode = s.ShopCode
join CashMachine as c on s.ShopCode = c.ShopCode
where c.CashMachineID=new.CashMachineID ))
then set new.CashierCode = NULL;
end if;
end;
```

Comment: Side notice: It should be `new.CashierCode`, not `new, CashierCode`. Is it just a misprint?

Comment: Thanks for this, yes I typed it wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like Column 'CashierCode' is defined as NOT NULL.  Are you sure you have a non null value for this column?

Looks like your trigger is trying to insert a NULL value to this column.  Change your table definition or provide a valid value in your trigger.

Comment: Yes, CashierCode is defined as NOT NULL. How can I change that ?

Comment: Instead of NULL  then you would need to come up with a convention in your system for "not" value.  Some use -1 or 0... 
If you are designing this system from scratch you can always alter your table definition to allow NULLS in the 'CashierCode' column.

Comment: Yes, it seems that the answer is "because you told MySQL that the CashierCode field can never be NULL"

Comment: @doublen: If it can be null, use `ALTER TABLE` : `ALTER TABLE table_name  CHANGE COLUMN CashierCode CashierCode [the same type as before] NULL ;`

Comment: Can you show me that not value convention please just to improve my knowledge?

Comment: Years ago I coded a system where one of the basic design decisions was to disallow NULL values throughout.
So the development team came up with a set of values that would represent "empty".  For example -1 for int.  So your team could design the system where you have these constants defined to use instead of NULL.  Keep in mind that you need to be sure that the constants you implement need to be guaranteed to NEVER match an actual value in your system.  (if you implement -1 = invalid 'CashierCode', then -1 can't be used as a 'CashierCode'.